Is this a resettable 1.25A fuse? (Nikon 1 J2 Power Board)
Am I correct in assuming that this is a 1.25A resettable fuse? There is a small component right next to the battery contacts that was blown, which I replaced with a new fuse. Unfortunately this didn't fix my issue (no power), so I checked this large component for both continuity and in diode mode. My multimeter shows OL in both measurement modes (diode mode measured in both directions).
Shorting the large component with a wire (I know, I know... the camera was super cheap and I'm aware this is not good practice) and using that replacement small fuse allowed the camera to power on again. I now want to replace the "P 125" component for everything to be as good as new again :)
Also, if it is a resettable fuse, does anyone know why it didn't reset again and just failed outright?


It's a Polytronics SMD1812P125TF/16 with a hold current of 1.25 A, so you are correct. Picture from LCSC to confirm:

Not sure how it failed, but these types of multilayer components can be damaged by mechanical stress.
